# Firebase.RemoteConfig working on pc and don't on android

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

I want to get [this parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcWzj.png).
I'm trying to do this with this code. But it's working only on pc.

Here is all my code but I need only to get parameters from Remote Config and initialize firebase analytics.

I can't figure out where is problem because there are few guides about it for unity.
I am trying to do this already 3 days please help.

```cs
    using UnityEngine;
    using Firebase.RemoteConfig;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Firebase.Crashlytics;
    using Firebase.Analytics;
    using Photon.Pun;
    using TMPro;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    
    public class GameOpening : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Text _versionText;
        [SerializeField] private RemoteConfigSavings _remoteConfigSavings;
        private Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = Firebase.DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;
        
        private int _version = -1;
        private int _receivedVersion
        {
            get => _version;
            set
            {
                _version = value;          
                UpdateConfig();
            }
        }
        private void Start()
        {
            AwakeFireBase();
            Invoke("ToNextScene", 1);
        }
        private void ToNextScene()
        {
            if(_version!=-1) PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(1);

            else Invoke("ToNextScene", 1);
        }
        private void AwakeFireBase()
        {
            if(Debug.isDebugBuild)
            {
                var configSettings = new ConfigSettings();
                configSettings.MinimumFetchInternalInMilliseconds = 0;
                FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance.SetConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);  
            }
    
            Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                FirebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
                dependencyStatus = task.Result;
                if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
                {
                    //InitializeFirebase();
                    GetGameVersion();
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
                }
            });
        }
    
        private void InitializeFirebase()
        {
            var defaults = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"someThing", "asdf"},
                {"some2", 12323}
            };

            FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance.SetDefaultsAsync(defaults).ContinueWith(task=> { GetGameVersion(); });
            Debug.Log("Remote config ready!");
        }
        private void GetGameVersion()
        {
            var remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance;
            remoteConfig.FetchAndActivateAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                IDictionary<string, ConfigValue> values = remoteConfig.AllValues;
                values.TryGetValue("VERSION", out ConfigValue objValue);
    
                int version = Convert.ToInt32(objValue.StringValue);
                _receivedVersion = version;
                _versionText.text = version.ToString();
            });
        }
        private void UpdateConfig()
        {
            _remoteConfigSavings.Version = _version;
            _remoteConfigSavings.SaveObject();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Before we start, we need to clean up our code.

I deleted everything except the part related to **FirebaseRemoteConfig**.
Also, I removed the `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()` and `SetDefaultsAsync()` parts.

After the code cleanup presented above, all that is left is the `GetGameVersion()` method. Now, let's find the problem.

### Problem

You should fully understand the description of `FetchAndActivateAsync()` in the [FirebaseRemoteConfig API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/remote-config/firebase-remote-config?authuser=0#class_firebase_1_1_remote_config_1_1_firebase_remote_config_1ac8959dadb409990ec73bca36daa5e920) page.

> **FetchAndActivateAsync()**
>
> If the time elapsed since the last fetch from the Firebase Remote Config backend is more than the **default minimum fetch interval**, configs are fetched from the backend.

Although not listed on this page, By default the minimum fetch interval is **12 hours**.

We change that part to `FetchAsync(TimeSpan.Zero)` because we want to check whether the value is updated or not in real time while developing.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using Firebase.Extensions;

public class GameOpening : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        GetGameVersion();
    }

    private static void GetGameVersion()
    {
        var remoteConfig = Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance;

        var fetchTask = remoteConfig.FetchAsync(TimeSpan.Zero)
            .ContinueWithOnMainThread(async task =>
            {
                await Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance.ActivateAsync();
                
                var values = remoteConfig.AllValues;
                values.TryGetValue("VERSION", out var configValue);
                
                Debug.Log(configValue.StringValue);
            });
    }
}
```

See why you used `ActivateAsync()`. There is a reason why we used **async await**.

> Note: This does not actually apply the data or make it accessible, it merely retrieves it and caches it. To accept and access the newly retrieved values, you must call `ActivateAsync()`. **Note that this function is asynchronous, and will normally take an unspecified amount of time before completion.**

All issues have been resolved. I also checked it on Android and it works fine. (Based on Samsung Galaxy 10 5G) (using LogCat)

---

Hope your problem is solved :)

Comment: await Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance.ActivateAsync();                  this line have   CS1061 'Task<bool>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<bool>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @anxl228 I just created a new project, tried again from scratch and it works. Did you just use the code I presented? Is your Unity version out of date? (I installed FirebaseRemote package and EDM4U version 1.2.171.)